# how to setup virtualenv to use a different python version in each virtual env

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

using `autoenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` in python and trying to configure in it the specific python version.

the autoenv file (called `.env`) contains (simply)

`echo 'my_env'`

is there a way to configure it's python version?

Comment: why not using mkvirtualenv command with --p option which lets you to choose the python version you need ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Answer (score 1):

When creating virtual environment, you can specify which python to use.
For example,

`virtualenv -p/usr/bin/python2.7 env`

Same for mkvirtualenv

Comment: you mean mkvirtualenv?